# Azure Pipeline - remove release definition (classic) version from version history

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In release definition's variables tab, I accidentally saved secret variable as plain text.
I have removed the secret stored as plain text, but in release definition version history I still see the secret.

Is it possible to remove an entry from release definition history?

Please note, the pipeline is not YAML file, nor is it in GIT repository.

Comment: You'll have to completely delete the release definition and recreate it. You can export/import release definitions, so it shouldn't be too painful.